# How to run ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript before Response.Redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, redirect, scriptmanager

How to run `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` before `Response.Redirect`

Script in `.ASPX` Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var soundObject3 = null;
        function PlaySoundComplete() {
            if (soundObject3 != null) {
                document.body.removeChild(soundObject3);
                soundObject3.removed = true;
                soundObject3 = null;
            }
            soundObject3 = document.createElement("embed");
            soundObject3.setAttribute("src", "Complete.wav");
            soundObject3.setAttribute("hidden", true);
            soundObject3.setAttribute("autostart", true);
            document.body.appendChild(soundObject3);
        }
</script>
```

Behide Code :

```
protected void AlertPlaySoundComplete()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "PlaySoundComplete()", true);
}
```

Call Method Function :

```
protected void BindDetail
{
   AlertPlaySoundComplete();
   string strRedirect = "confirm.aspx?Item=" + strMat + "," + Customer+ "," + intReasonID.ToString() + "," + Delivery;
   Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
}
```

This code is not run function `AlertPlaySoundComplete();` but redirect now in BindDetail. I'll to run `AlertPlaySoundComplete();` before Redirect page

Comment: You can't. The request will send an HTTP 302 response to the browser and the browser will follow the URL you send it back to the server again. There isn't any code to run until the server responds to the URL that has been redirected to (the first HTTP 200 response). This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - perhaps you should rephrase it to "How do I get a sound to play before redirecting?" and you might get better answers.

Comment: I want to play sound bedore redirect page